# apply fucntion within class to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, class

i have a class with two functions within it

```
import pandas as pd


class fees():

    def __init__(self):
        self.total_fee = 0

    def base_fee(self, value):
        if value <= 200:
            fee = value * 0.1
            self.total_fee += fee
            return fee 

        elif value > 200:
            fee = value * 0.07
            self.total_fee += fee
            return fee


    def com_fee(self, value):
        if value <= 10:
            fee = value*0.2
            self.total_fee += fee
            return fee

        elif value > 10:
            fee = value *0.1
            self.total_fee += fee
            return fee
```

This returns a total fee within in. However i am also trying to use the functions within the class to add two columns to the dataframe below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'person': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'total_spend': [1000, 150, 45],
        'additional_spend': [25, 5, 0]
        })
```

The result would be

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'person': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'total_spend': [1000, 150, 45],
        'additional_spend': [25, 5, 0],
        'base_fee': [70, 15, 4.5],
        'com_fee': [7, 1.5, 0]
        })
```

The only thing i have tried is applying the function with lambda x: but unsure how to call the function from the class. There are probably better ways.

Comment: Why not add one more variable in each of the class and return that too with the total_fee?

Comment: would that then work with apply or a loop?

Comment: Apply or a loop on what? What exactly you want to use these functions for?

Comment: i want to use the base_fee function on df['total_spend] to give df1['base_fee'] and the com_fee function on df['addtional_spend'] to give df1['com_fee']

Comment: you are using them as class functions. Then you should not use them for apply. You can simply iterate over all the values and call them.

Comment: great thanks. That works. wasn't sure what the best way was.